# LLVM: Get function argument locations (ABI)

Tags: llvm, clang, llvm-clang

I'd like to write a LLVM plugin to tell me: for each function declaration, how many general purpose register, XMM register, and stack arguments the function will have. This only needs to work for the x86 SYSV calling convention. Is this currently possible? If so, any direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but slightly tricky, LLVM seems to be much more friendly when you attempt to manipulate IR than when messing with Machine specific code. There's no easy way to add passes, for one.
Also note that the eventual number of registers used depends on how virtual registers are eventually allocated into real x86 logical register, where spilling may occur in some cases, and elimination of some variables in others. So you're not only prevented to work on IR where values are in SSA form, you actually need to work on the very last stages of CodeGen. To make things more interesting, it also depends on the level of optimization you use.
Check out - llvm/lib/CodeGen/Passes.cpp, look at addOptimizedRegAlloc or addFastRegAlloc, check out the passed called inside and use the last ones (implemented in separate files in CodeGen), to hitch a ride on. The internal loops should be pretty straight forward, but you'll need to run your bookkeeping based on the X86 target regs enumerated in TargetRegisterInfo